# Unable to install development app on iphone

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using xcode 11.3.1 to archive an app. I have set my profile correctly and run the same ipa to multiple devices. I have an new iphone device with ios 10.0.1 to which I can't install the archive. I have added the device's udid in the profile. I create development archive.

The error on device is Unable to Download App. "App" could not be downloaded at this time.
Any thoughts?

Comment: what is the error @billysk

Comment: I did the appropriate edit

Comment: Is any error on the xcode?

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: Can you please try installing the ipa directly through Xcode and see if it is installing in device

Answer (score 4):

The provisioning profile must not have the newly added iPhone UUID.

Do following checks.

`1. Rename your AppName.ipa file to AppName.zip
 2. Unzip the file to get Payload.
 3. Run below command on terminal
security cms -D -i /PATH_TO_PAYLOAD_DIR/Payload/appName.app/embedded.mobileprovision`
 
and check your included devices UUID's.

Comment: I did this and I saw the new device's uuid in the list.

Comment: Then you should be able to install the app without any issues. 
Please check the deployment target too. Also check the development profile on mac has updated UUID's

Comment: The target is 9.0 and the development profile has also the newly added UUID. Is there any possibility that the fact that i have not set the new iphone with apple account account is the reason i can't install the app. Trought is that i have already installed it to other devices with no apple account also.

Comment: Are you doing this by connecting the device to mac and then installing through xcode, or downloading the app from MDM or itunes?

Comment: I upload ipa, manifest.plist and a html pointing to manifest to a server and then I download the app throught the html

Comment: Can you try to redo the same process again, looks like issue with mismatch of UUID's in provisioning profile. Just give it a try again with a small app, let me know if that does not work

Comment: I tried with another app in whose profile i added two uuids. One of those was the device the problem occurs and I couldn't install app again. At the other device it did installed . It seems like there is a problem with the exact device

Comment: can you please check again if the deployment target is correct, I don't think the provisioning profile should cause this issue

Comment: Looks that way, please make sure once again your UUID is correct and deployment target is also set correctly

Comment: Ios deployment target is 9.0 and device's software is ios 10.0.1 . I've triple checked that UUID is correct

Comment: If I plug the device to my mac and install the app through xcode it installs with no problem. Weird right?

Comment: Hi @billysk, any resolution to the defect? i am also able to install through xcode but not after i archive?

Comment: No unfortunately i didn't find something. I think i was able to drag n drop ipa to device and it installed but i'm not sure i remember correctly